# Adding point listener to Network Graph AnyChart

Tags: events, networking, anychart

I am trying to use AnyChart to open specific url's based on the node that is clicked in the graph. However, pointClick doesn't seem to work;

JavaScript;

```
anychart.data.loadJsonFile("levels.json", function (data) {

        var chart = anychart.graph(data);

...

chart.listen("pointClick", function(e){
            open_level(e);
});

...

function open_level(e){
    var level = e.iterator.get("url")
    window.open(level);
}
```

A node is given in .JSON by;

```
"id": "Earth",
      "height": 60,
      "url": "Earth.html" (local HTML file)
    },
```

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Network graph implements a different event system as it includes nodes and edges simultaneously. So, you can achieve the desired interactivity like is described in [the sample we prepared](https://playground.anychart.com/VEKKIOFF/1).